# vuejs2/vuex: How to prevent multiple subscriptions to mutations?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Within my components, I'm subscribing to datastore mutations:

```
mounted() {
    this.$dataStore.subscribe((mutation, state) => console.log(mutation));
},
```

However, when I open this view/component `n` times, I'm getting `n` subscriptions and I see multiple log entries for a single mutation.

How can I prevent that? Why are subscriptions not removed after a new component has been loaded?

**Edit**: I know tried the following, since the `subscribe` function returns the `unsubscribe` function:

```
 mounted() {
        this.unsub = this.$dataStore.subscribe((mutation, state) => console.log(mutation));
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.unsub();
    },
```

It seems to be working, but I don't know if this is even remotely how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: is it the same component or is the component rendered to the page multiple times (like in a loop)?

Comment: it's the same component. It's only rendered once.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is expected behavior because when you have `n` components subscribed to store mutations you generally want all these components to update/do something when a mutation occurs. Otherwise you should conditionally add the subscription in certain situations. When you [destroy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#destroyed) a component all event listeners should be destroyed however.

Comment: Thank you. I see, but I don't understand why the same component should subscribe multiple times. I also fail to understand how I can unsubscribe from the `destroyed` event. I know the subscribe functions returns the unsubscribe function, but how can I pass it over to the `destroy` event so I can call it there?

Comment: I believe the way you unsubscribe in your edit is the correct way of doing it (using the returned unsubscribe function in beforeDestroyed()). Depending on what exactly you are trying to do you could consider using a watcher to solve your problem since these don't duplicate on component re-creation. I also made a fiddle you can play or test with: https://jsfiddle.net/davn5bbp/10/